# Getting Tomcat to play well with Netbeans 6.7 on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, netbeans, netbeans6.7, gentoo

I have an external Tomcat server configured to run J2EE applications on my development (Gentoo Linux install) machine. This works great if the server is started prior to opening Netbeans and deploying the code [within the IDE]. This fails when I try to restart the server or to debug the server application. The error I get is that it is unable to find "catalina.sh" and the shutdown/start scripts for tomcat.

The Gentoo guide for this suggests that the scripts were outdated and were replaced with the init.d scripts. Does anyone have a suggestion on where I could find these scripts or how they solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of a script is due to an issue with the Gentoo Tomcat ebuild... all of the script files were in the bin directory of the src build.

[Gentoo Bug Site](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276059)

Solution: 
1. un-tar the src

2. Copy all of the script files into the tomcat/bin directory
3. Change group ownership of the script files to tomcat
4. Enable execute and write group permissions to the script files